# How to properly set keras output layer name to work with utensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I want to use [utensor](https://github.com/uTensor/uTensor) with my `keras` script.

`Utensor` needs `.pb` file and output layer name to work, so I set name for output layer:

```
model.add(Dense(13, activation='softmax', name='predict'))
```

Convert `keras` model to `pb` file and run `utensor-cli`:

```
utensor-cli convert model.pb --output-nodes=predict
```

But seems `utensor` cannot find `predict` layer name:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/victor/miniconda3/envs/cube/bin/utensor-cli", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/home/victor/miniconda3/envs/cube/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 764, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/victor/miniconda3/envs/cube/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 717, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/victor/miniconda3/envs/cube/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1137, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/victor/miniconda3/envs/cube/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 956, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/victor/miniconda3/envs/cube/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/victor/miniconda3/envs/cube/lib/python3.6/site-packages/utensor_cgen/cli.py", line 84, in convert_graph
    generator.generate(model_path)
  File "/home/victor/miniconda3/envs/cube/lib/python3.6/site-packages/utensor_cgen/backend/code_generator.py", line 50, in generate
    ugraph = parser_cls.parse(self.model_file, self.output_nodes)
  File "/home/victor/miniconda3/envs/cube/lib/python3.6/site-packages/utensor_cgen/frontend/tensorflow.py", line 57, in parse
    topologic_order_graph(ugraph)
  File "/home/victor/miniconda3/envs/cube/lib/python3.6/site-packages/utensor_cgen/utils.py", line 218, in topologic_order_graph
    visit(node_name)
  File "/home/victor/miniconda3/envs/cube/lib/python3.6/site-packages/utensor_cgen/utils.py", line 207, in visit
    op_info = ugraph.ops_info[node_name]
KeyError: 'predict'
```